# Is there a way to specify a secret for all environments in secrets.yml from rails 4.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Like the question states, is there a way to make a secret known to all 3 environments without copy and pasting like this?

secrets.yml

```
development:
  secret_key_base: ...
  my_global_secret: foo

test:
  secret_key_base: ...
  my_global_secret: foo

production:
  secret_key_base: ...
  my_global_secret: foo
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can define and share a common key using `&label` and `<<: *label`

```
common: &common
  secret_key_base: ...
  my_global_secret: foo

development:
  <<: *common
  something_specific_to_development: ...

test:
  <<: *common
  something_specific_to_test: ...

production:
  <<: *common
  something_specific_to_production: ...
```

### Update: For Rails 5.1+

Rails 5.1 adds the `shared` key which is automatically applied to all environments:

```
shared: # Everything nested under this key is automatically shared
  secret_key_base: ...
  my_global_secret: "foo"

development:
  my_global_secret: "override value for dev"

test:
  ...
```

Comment: Rails 5.1 adds the new `shared` section which is automatically applied to all environments. (without needing to be named or inherited like `<<: *common` is)

Answer (score 1):

Using `common: &common` didn't work for me with Rails 5.1 - `shared:` did though.

Comment: The old answer should still work (maybe you forgot to inherit the named `&common` section?) but Rails 5.1 does add the new `shared` section which is automatically applied to all environments. (without needing to be named or inherited like `<<: *common` is)

Comment: Got it @mltsy - I'll see if I can find time to double check!